# CSS transition not working with classList.add

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Good, I’ve been an hour and I’m going crazy (I’m new)
I have a button that when pressed shows a div . Fixed sidemenu, this occupies 100% high and wide and contains two divs, one that does black background with some transparency and occupies everything and a white side menu.
I want that when you activate the open button or the close button or touch the black background transparently, the background and menu appear or disappear but with a transition and I do not know why it does not work, the menu with a side transition and the menu going from 0 to . 2 of opacity or vice versa when closed

See if anyone can explain why it does not work, thank you very much in advance :)

```js
const sidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu')
const sidemenuContent = document.getElementById('sidemenu__content')
const abrirSidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu__open')
const cerrarSidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu__close')
const sidemenubg = document.getElementById('fondo-modal')


abrirSidemenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.add('show-sidemenu')
  sidemenuContent.classList.add('sidemenuContent__animation')
  sidemenubg.classList.add('opacity__animation')
})
cerrarSidemenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.remove('show-sidemenu')
  sidemenuContent.classList.remove('sidemenuContent__animation')
  sidemenubg.classList.remove('opacity__animation')
})
sidemenubg.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.remove('show-sidemenu')
  sidemenuContent.classList.remove('sidemenuContent__animation')
  sidemenubg.classList.remove('opacity__animation')
})
```

```css
.sidemenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fondo-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.sidemenu__content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -350px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 5rem 2rem 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: .5s;
}

.show-sidemenu {
  display: grid;
}

.sidemenuContent__animation {
  left: 0;
}

.opacity__animation {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div class="topmenu__left">
  <button id="sidemenu__open">OPEN</button>
  <div class="sidemenu" id="sidemenu">
    <div class="fondo-modal" id="fondo-modal"></div>
    <div class="sidemenu__content" id="sidemenu__content">
      <button id="sidemenu__close">CLOSE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major issue is that you're trying to transition the `display` attribute, which cannot be transitioned: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp So instead, we'll define your display attribute as you like but we'll add the opacity and visibility attributes and make those our goal for transition. We'll also specify a timing operation with linear which you can change at your discretion (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) and we'll transition everything for the sake of keeping it simple since you don't have any real need for specificity here. Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions :)

Edit: added a light-blue to the body just so you can see everything happening but you can take that out obviously.

```js
const sidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu');
const sidemenuContent = document.getElementById('sidemenu__content');
const abrirSidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu__open');
const cerrarSidemenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu__close');
const sidemenubg = document.getElementById('fondo-modal');


abrirSidemenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.add('show-sidemenu');
  sidemenuContent.classList.add('sidemenuContent__animation');
  sidemenubg.classList.add('opacity__animation');
});
cerrarSidemenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.remove('show-sidemenu');
  sidemenuContent.classList.remove('sidemenuContent__animation');
  sidemenubg.classList.remove('opacity__animation');
});
sidemenubg.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidemenu.classList.remove('show-sidemenu');
  sidemenuContent.classList.remove('sidemenuContent__animation');
  sidemenubg.classList.remove('opacity__animation');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sidemenu {
  display: grid;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fondo-modal {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.sidemenu__content {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -350px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 5rem 2rem 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.show-sidemenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.sidemenuContent__animation {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.opacity__animation {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="topmenu__left">
  <button id="sidemenu__open">OPEN</button>
  <div class="sidemenu" id="sidemenu">
    <div class="fondo-modal" id="fondo-modal">modal</div>
    <div class="sidemenu__content" id="sidemenu__content">
      <button id="sidemenu__close">CLOSE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i didn't know the property visibility, so the only difference is that with display none the element is not displayed while with visibility hidden it is not seen but still takes up space?

Comment: Basically. And you don’t have to use visibility necessarily, that’s just the route I took for the example. You can transition most css attributes in general (just not display!) so feel free to be creative with your experimentation of transitions :)

Comment: But for this case you can use anything other than visibility? Why do I want the whole background to go from 0 to . 2 of opacity in . 5s, if it was a position animation, you could skip the visibility, but in this case not?

Comment: @Karoly That was meant to be more of a clarification that you don't have to use visibility for every instance of something like this, that's just the approach I took on your example because it fits. I apologize if I misphrased it, I just didn't want to paint it as "you have to do it this way because reasons" but rather leave it open-ended so when you're working on layouts in the future it encourages you to try various solutions and not just run with the same thing every time.

Comment: @AStombaugh, this is right on.  Turns out had complicated the transitions based on other SOF questions.  This worked well.  Thanks